# VS Code terminal becomes unusable

Tags: visual-studio-code

First, before someone flags this questions as *"out of topic"* I will say that first I intended it to post it at stack exchange Meta. But at doing so it clearly says: "Ask your question in Stack Overflow if your question is about programming" and the use of programming tools such as Vscode *is about programming*

That being said, I use vscode for coding, and lately I have started to use its terminal (before I used the linux terminal). So far everything ok but I have noticed that after using it, and leaving it for some time (and sometimes closing the PC) the terminal becomes unusable, the messages invisible and even if I type, the letters are not visualized.

Why would this be happening and is there a way to avoid this. Right now there is no way and I have to just lose my work there and open another terminal

Comment: You're correct as this is off-topic. Yes, it's a tool that can be used for programming, but as written, your question has nothing to do with programming. Also, it's not for meta.stackoverflow.com either - that is for questions about Stack Overflow.

Comment: Regarding your vscode issue: you really haven't provided enough detail to even guess what's happening. Maybe this fits on SuperUser (general computing), but you would need to provide more details about what's happening.

Comment: which is the forum for *programmers* and *developers* (not general users) and the tools they use for their work?

Comment: Yes, but your question isn't about tool+programming (e.g. trying to debug something, some code-based setting, etc). It's about a program that locks up. This is completely unrelated to anything to do with programming. And even if this *was* on-topic here: the question still doesn't have enough detail (but again... not on-topic here)

Comment: I am not arguing. I am *asking* where in stack exchange, I can put a question related directly with developers's work